# WSS tools for VS2008 directory question

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, wss, wss-3.0, vsewss

I want to place an aspx inside the TEMPLATE->LAYOUTS folder of the server running WSS.
Should I create the same folder structure under the pkg folder of visual studio or under the project root?

In other words should I do this

pkg->TEMPLATE->LAYOUTS or this

project root->TEMPLATE->LAYOUTS

Also where should I place the elements.xml and features.xml

Thanks, as you may thought I'm starting developing with VSeWSS tools for VS2008

Answer (score 0):

Place the folders under your project root. And, it should be "Templates":

```
project root -> Templates -> LAYOUTS
```

I'd place the .XML files under the `pkg` folder hierarchy, though.